How to handle transient errors from Sitecore IP Geolocation service
We have been using the Sitecore IP Geolocation service for over 3 years. During that time, when making calls to Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GetInformationByIp(), we have seen various instances of System.Net.WebException such as:

The remote name could not be resolved: 'geoip-ces.cloud.sitecore.net'
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.
The operation has timed out
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

The frequency of these errors vary from month to month, and while they do seem to be transient, they occur regularly enough that we want to start handling the errors.
A few ideas are to:

Retry with exponential backoff
Make a call to an alternative geolocation service
Leverage geolocation information from the CDN (info is often limited, though)

What do you recommend?

Are you certain you need to handle these?  Unless they persisted and never went away, I would assume the service will just retry them at a later point in time.

In our project, We are highly dependent on GEO IP Service, and most of the time it just works and we do not have any issues
But yes because it deals with your license and you have to create service request to activate it and if it is not activated in those time, You generally get some issues, But otherwise it just works
My purpose of saying is, There are guidelines using which you can easily hook other provider but i would suggest not to go that unknown routes where you might face some different types of issues
According to me, GEO IP Service just works most of the time, Though you might need to show some informative banner or some fall back IP or Country, If your front end functionalities are dependent on it and if you get error from GEP IP to make sure you are fail safe.
